# What is the easiest way to get an echoed or returned string from php into jquery/ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say that I have in my test.php:

```
echo 'Hello, world'
```

And I want to place that text in a div.

This doesn't work for me and the alert also does not pop out.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "test.php",
   data : data,
   success: function(msg){
     alert('Does it Work?');
     ("#div_1").html(message);
 });
```

Comment: You have firebug installed? What does it say? Is it even finding the file, as in URL: "test.php", is it locating that file ok?

Comment: You don't have valid javascript there. You're missing closing braces. Do you get any errors? Can you see the request using Firebug? Does the request give you a response if you open it in a new tab?

Comment: Fixed the typo, i rushed when typing the post. But no, no errors come out in my script.

Comment: Your success callback has a 'msg' parameter but then instead of using it you use 'message.txt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get('test.php',function(data) { alert('data:'+data); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, that may be the issue (you forgot to close a curly bracket and a parenthesis). Try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    data : data,
    success: function(msg){
      alert('Does it Work?');
      $("#div_1").html(message.txt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$("#div_1").load("test.php", data);
```

This places the HTML output from `test.php` directly into the `#div_1` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "test.php",
   data : data,
   success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
     $("#div_1").html(msg);
   }
 });
```

Comment: still missing a closing brace

Comment: @bemace ahhh yeah... didn't notice that :D thanks...updated my post :)